# Computer Science Stack Exchange

Tags: discussion, status-completed, other-se-sites

Update:

The [Computer Science - Stack Exchange](https://cs.stackexchange.com/) has entered public beta.

---

The [Computer Science proposal](http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/35636/computer-science?referrer=pdx8p7tVWqozXN85c5ibxQ2) is almost there and only needs 12 more commitments. You should commit soon if you are interested and want to participate in the private beta.

Comment: Staggeringly close now. Just two more!

Comment: And now it's in !

Comment: Closed beta is running now.